# Как на Android послать Post-запрос с массивом в качестве параметра?

Tags: android, http, post

Как отправить Post-запрос с массивом в качестве параметра. Обычно я использую *Volley*, но не могу задать в качестве единого параметра массив. перепробовал по разному.

После смены *buildTools* и *support*  org.apache.http больше не работает. Альтернатив не нахожу, может кто знает как осуществить это на *Volley* или как-то иначе?

P.S.: Проверил на *Postman* - если посылать множество одноименных параметров то это прокатывает, но в *Volley* параметры хранятся в HashMap с уникальными ключами и такой способ не прокатит.

Comment: Post запрос синхронный? Ajax подойдет?

Comment: ассинхронный, в андройде можно воспользоваться ajax'ом?

Comment: Сори, недочитал про андроид. Но тогда не очень понятно в чем конретно сложность? 
Возможно это поможет http://stackoverflow.com/a/31552547/2003555

Comment: Бывает) Спасибо за ссылку, но не поможет)

Comment: Если пост такой
?post[]=value&$post[]=value2&post[]=value3 
то придёт соответственно массив, может попробывать сформировать тело запроса таким образом...

Comment: Запрос имеет два параметра : 1) ключ - уникальный ключ и список значений - спосок значечений(name = value1&name=value2...)ХешМап - в итоге хранит одно значение, в урл подставлять - не вариант, метод сменить - не вариант, единым объектом пытался посылать  - не вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С *Volley* так и не получилось настроить что-то путное. Подключить org.apache.http не удалось. Пришлось использовать рекомендуемый "гуглами" вариант [*HttpURLConnection*](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) .

В качестве примера запроса использовал [подобное](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post) , а массив перед преобразованием в строку и отправкой в запрос хранился в *HashMap<Строка,Список>*